# Object Hash Lookup with `eqv`

Tags: raku

Is there a way to use `eqv` to lookup a hash value without looping over the key-value pairs when using object keys?

It is possible to use object keys in a hash by specifying the key's type at declaration:

```
class Foo { has $.bar };
my Foo $a .= new(:bar(1));
my %h{Foo} = $a => 'A', Foo.new(:bar(2)) => 'B';
```

However, key lookup uses the identity operator `===` which will return the value only if it is the same object and not an equivalent one:

```
my Foo $a-prime .= new(:bar(1));
say $a eqv $a-prime;   # True
say $a === $a-prime;   # False
say %h{$a};            # A
say %h{$a-prime};      # (Any)
```

Comment: How serious is your application?  I have an answer which would not be acceptable in any production environment but if your just exploring what's possible for fun it may be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for "==="](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/%3D%3D%3D), the last line reveals that the operator is based on **.WHICH** and that *"... all value types must override method WHICH."*  This is why if you create two separate items with the same string value, **"==="** returns **True**.

```
my $a = "Hello World";
my $b = join " ", "Hello", "World";

say $a === $b;     # True even though different items - because same value
say $a.WHICH ;     # "Str|Hello World"
say $b.WHICH ;     # (same as above) which is why "===" returns True
```

So, instead of creating your own container type or using some of the hooks for [subscripts](http://doc.perl6.org/language/subscripts#Custom_type_example), you could instead copy the way "value types" do it - i.e. butcher (some what) the idea of identity.  The .WHICH method for strings shown above simply returns the type name and contents joined with a **'|'**.  Why not do the same thing;

```
class Foo {
    has $.bar;
    multi method WHICH(Foo:D:) { "Foo|" ~ $!bar.Str }
}

my Foo $a .= new(:bar(1));
my %h{Foo} = $a => 'A', Foo.new(:bar(2)) => 'B';

my Foo $a-prime .= new(:bar(1));
say $a eqv $a-prime;   # True
say $a === $a-prime;   # True
say %h{$a};            # A
say %h{$a-prime};      # A
```

There is a small cost, of course - the concept of identity for the instances of this class is, well - let's say interesting.  What are the repercussions?  The only thing that comes immediately to mind, is if you plan to use some sort of object persistence framework, its going to squish different instances that *now look the same* into one (perhaps).

Different objects with the same attribute data are going to be  indistinguishable - which is why I hesitated before posting this answer.  OTOH, its your class, its your app so, depending on the size/importance etc, it may be a fine way to do it.

Comment: I was hoping for a trait that could be used at definition. Unfortunately for me src/core/Hash.pm is predominately npq. The src does give an example of how this might be done with the TypeHash role. Perhaps using a duck type for objects implementing a HASH-CODE method would be possible instead of WHICH.

Comment: I believe the native objects are done in nqp as perl6 doesn't exist at that point (if you know what I mean).  As perl6 users, we can build metaobjects in perl6 (ie forget about nqp if you want to).  However you do it though, you are going to be mapping different objects ($a vs $a-prime) to the same key so explicitly fiddling with identity to make that clear might be a good idea.  Perhaps implement "keyWHICH" or "myVALUE" or some such and make a custom hash use it for key differentiation.  Still, the technique I suggested is not bad for one extra line (if I do say so myself) :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the buildin postcircumfix, provide your own.

```
class Foo { has $.bar };
my Foo $a .= new(:bar(1));
my %h{Foo} = $a => 'A', Foo.new(:bar(2)) => 'B';


multi sub postcircumfix:<{ }>(\SELF, WhateverCode $c) is raw {
    gather for SELF.keys -> $k {
        take $k if $c($k)
    }
}

dd %h;
dd %h{* eqv $a};
```

OUTPUT

```
Hash[Any,Foo] %h = (my Any %{Foo} = (Foo.new(bar => 1)) => "A", (Foo.new(bar => 2)) => "B")
(Foo.new(bar => 1),).Seq
```